# Removing tags in lisp program

Tags: xml, tags, lisp

I need help programming something.  I'm coding in Common Lisp, and I'm trying to delete tags out of a list of strings.  I read in a file in XML format, and my goal is to remove any text that appears between `<` and `>`, and if the tag begins with `?xml`, then that entire line needs to be removed.  I know there are [`remove`/`delete`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_rm_rm.htm)/ functions for use on the command line, but I'm trying to make this removal happen in my actual Lisp code and I can't figure out how to do it.  Every time I try I get an error.

Right now here's my code for reading in the file(it works):

```lisp
;;;Program: Lisp Assignment 1
;;;Author: Mouse

(defun file-lines (file)
;;;returns a list of strings and the number of
;;;lines read.
    (with-open-file (i file)
    (loop for line = (read-line i nil nil)
          and line-count from 0
          while line
          collect line into lines
          finally (return (values lines line-count)))))
```

My idea is that after the line that says `while line`, I'll have to input code to check for the tags, but I don't know what to use.  Every time I've called a `remove` or `delete` method, I get an error.  I don't know if I'm not calling them right or something.  Could someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is not very clear. Why do you ask about deleting tags from a list of strings, while your example code reads lines from a file? Assuming you really are asking about a list of strings, may tags be spread over multiple of those strings or not? Also, you ask about `remove` and `delete` without mentioning what you have really tried and how it failed. If you want to change the contents of the file directly, well, you cannot just delete things from the stream and expect that to work.

Here is a naive approach to remove tags by reading from a stream character by character:

```
(defun remove-tags (string)
  (flet ((read-tag (instream)
           (loop for char = (read-char instream nil nil)
                 while (not (string= char #\>)))))
    (with-output-to-string (outstream)
      (with-input-from-string (instream string)
        (loop for char = (read-char instream nil nil)
              while char
              if (char= char #\<) do (read-tag instream)
              else do (write-char char outstream))))))


CL-USER> (remove-tags "<p><a href=\"foo\">bar</a> frob <emph>baz</emph> quux</p>")
"bar frob baz quux"
```

If you want to read from and write to a file, just substitute `with-output-to-string` and `with-input-from-string` with the according `with-open-file` forms.

But this is just an example to get you started. Even if this is just an academic exercise, you need to make it more robust. For example, it fails for:

```
CL-USER> (remove-tags "<p><a href=\"fo>o\">bar</a>")
"o\">bar"
```

(Unescaped closing angle brackets are allowed in XML strings, if I remember correctly.)

Also, this is neither tested nor optimized for speed in any way – processing character-wise *might* be too slow, and it does not handle the removal of the `?xml` tag. All that is left as an exercise for the reader.

For *practical* purposes, you should probably really just use one of the XML libraries, or maybe use regexen and pray. Parsing and processing XML is a problem that has been solved in many libraries in almost any language in practial use, and there are lots of details to get wrong (maybe not if you really just want to remove some tags and that's it, but *principiis obsta*), and it makes for a rather boring exercise anyway.